# accessing state data in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

Why is it not possible to access this.state.board within componentDidMount? As I understand it, once the component has been rendered, componentDidMount is fired immediately after, and only once.

I am trying to set up a Google Analytics ecommerce tracker, and so I thought the best place to set that up would be within the componentDidMount because it ensures that the GA tracker is called only once. However, I am not able to access any of the state data to send back to GA. Any ideas?

```
    //function which establishes state
    function getEditorState() {
        var board = Editor.getCsb();
        var similarBoard = Editor.getSimilarLsbs();
        return {
            board: board,
            similarBoard: similarBoard,
            editing: Editor.isEditing(),
            hoverColor: Editor.getHoverColor(),
            variant: Editor.variant(),
            lidAndLsb: Editor.getLidAndLsb()
        };
    }



  //component    
    var CsbEditorApp = React.createClass({

            getInitialState: function () {
                return getEditorState();
            },

            componentDidMount: function () {
              console.log(this.state.board); // <---- this returns an empty object.
              Editor.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
              SbAction.loadCsb(this.props.params.cid);
           }, 

           render: function() {
             console.log(this.state.board); // <---- this returns the the board object with data. 
           return (
            <div className={cm('lightbox sb-bg overlay-border')} ref="app">
                <Header board={this.state.board} label={this.state.label} socialLinkStatus={this.state.socialLinkStatus} buyingAll={this.state.buyingAll} />
                <div className="viewer-content">
                    <div id="csb-content">
                        <MetaText className="meta-author" metaKey="author" board={this.state.board} />
                        <BoardMeta board={this.state.board}/>
                        <CsbPanel board={this.state.board hoverColor={this.state.hoverColor} showPanel={showPanel} />

                        <RouteHandler/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }, 
 _onChange: function () {
        this.setState(getEditorState());
        $("#cc_hover").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @LuisPinto I added my code

Comment: can you try putting your getEditorState() inside the component?

Comment: @LuisPinto if I make getEditorState() a method on the CsbEditorApp  class,  the results are the same. the state of the board within the componentDidMount does not contain any data.

Comment: Maybe can be because you try to console.log the state before it is created. Can you try put in the function an empty object without calling Editor.getCsb() etc...

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is not a reliable method of debugging - the method is async and actually can get called after you've set up your listener or even after the callback it registers (which affects the state) has been triggered, so use the debugger. Also, try commenting out the `Editor.addChangeListener(this._onChange);` line and see if it causes the problem.